# How to extend and override rules config in ESLint?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I am setting up ESLint config files between two packages (one for web and one for UI) in monorepo ReactJS, I want to extend some configs from base Eslint for my web Eslint but I have a problem with that.

*./base.json* (the config will be applied for UI only)

```
{
    "extends": ["next", "prettier"],
    "plugins": ["prettier", "@typescript-eslint", "unused-imports"],
    "rules": {
      
        "no-unused-vars": "off", 
        "no-duplicate-imports": "off",
        "no-console": "warn", 
        "no-return-await": "warn",
        "no-useless-return": "warn",
        "no-var": "warn",

        "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "off", 

        "import/order": [
            "warn",
            {
                "groups": ["type", "builtin", "external", "internal", "parent", "sibling", "index", "object"],                
                "newlines-between": "always"
            }
        ],
    }
}
```

*./web.json* (the config will be applied for web and extends from base.json)

```
{
    "extends": ["./base.json", "next/core-web-vitals"],
    "rules": {             
        "@next/next/no-img-element": "off",

        "import/order": [
            "warn",
            {
                "groups": ["type", "builtin", "external", "internal", "parent", "sibling", "index", "object"],
                "pathGroups": [
                    {
                        "pattern": "@/custom/**",
                        "group": "internal"
                    },                  
                ],
                "newlines-between": "always",
            }
        ],
    }
}
```

Following the code above, I am extending from base configs with new `pathGroups` property added in `import/order` but I have to rewrite `import/order` again. So how can I avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"extends": ["./base.json", "next/core-web-vitals"],
"overrides": [
    {
        "files": ["**/*.js"],  // Adjust the pattern to match your JavaScript files
        "rules": {
            "import/order": [
                "warn",
                {
                    "groups": ["type", "builtin", "external", "internal", "parent", "sibling", "index", "object"],
                    "pathGroups": [
                        {
                            "pattern": "@/custom/**",
                            "group": "internal"
                        },
                    ],
                    "newlines-between": "always"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
}
```

Here is how you can modify your web.json